# MATLAB wont open after java heap memory change

Tags: matlab, memory, heap-size

I changed the Java heap memory from 128 MB to 4096 GB and now MATLAB will not open.

I am using Windows 7 and I have actually had this problem before a long time ago and there was a way I could change the memory back in a file somewhere, but I cannot remember the file name or location.

Someone please help me. I think this is a relatively simple problem. I don't understand why MATLAB wont start after increasing the java heap memory. My system has 16 GB of RAM and this doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings file (for R2014b in Windows) lives at:

```
%AppData%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\matlab.prf
```

For Linux, and presumably also OS X:

```
$HOME/.matlab/R2014b/matlab.prf
```

You may also be able to locate the preferences file more reliably if you can launch MATLAB with the `-nojvm` option (thanks Amro):

```
fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf') % if you can get into MATLAB
```

The setting to look for is (example with 512 MB):

```
JavaMemHeapMax=I512
```

Edit that and start MATLAB.  If that doesn't work, backup the whole folder and start again with fresh settings.

If you have a 32-bit installation of MATLAB, then 4096MB heap size might cause problems.  Just a guess.

Comment: A platform-independent way to locate the file: `fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf')`

Comment: @Amro Nice.  Can I add to the answer?  However, it's a bit of an issue _when you can't start MATLAB_.  ;)  BTW, what is it in Linux? `.matlab/R2014b/`?

Comment: I suppose you could start with `-nojvm`, if that's still supported.

Comment: Just checked - `$HOME/.matlab/R2014a` it is for my 2014a version. Either way `fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf')` as suggested by Amro should work OS independently.